# How do I wrap `cc_binary`/`cc_library` into a custom rule (not macro!)?

Tags: bazel, bazel-cpp

In order to work around a [bug](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/4605), and in order to set platform-specific compiler options, I want to wrap `cc_binary` (and `cc_library`) into a custom rule.
I do not want to use a macro, as then I'd have to structure my code like that:

```
deps = select(
        {
            "@platforms//os:linux": deps + ["my-extra-dep"],
            "//conditions:default": deps,
        }
// repeat the same for copts and defines
```

Instead, I'd like to structure my code like that:

```
// checks @platforms//os:linux
if is_linux():
  deps = deps + ["my-extra-dep"]
  defines = defines + ["custom-define1", ...]
```

The latter is only possible in a rule, where one can query platform attributes.
In a macro, I'd be stuck `select`ing every individual attribute.

My issue is with the boilerplate of my custom rule - what should the `attrs` be, so that I can transparently forward to the native `cc_binary`/`cc_library` rule? Am I missing an easy way to do this that is not translating the entire interface specification of the `cc_*` rules into starlark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no generic way to reuse a different rule at the rule-implementation level. However, there are ways to make `select` trees more succinct. For instance:

```py
def on_linux(d):
   return select({"@platforms//os:linux": d, "//conditions:default": []})

def macro(deps, defines):
   ...
   deps += on_linux(["my-extra-dep"])
   defines += on_linux(["custom-define", "custom-define2"])
```